# Find function $ f $ such that $f(\frac{x-3}{x+1})+f(\frac{x+3}{1-x})=x$

Tags: functional-equations

I am looking for functions $ f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ satisfying
$$f\Big(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\Big)+f\Big(\frac{x+3}{1-x}\Big)=x$$

I used the substitution $ x=\cos(2t) $ for $ x\in (0,2\pi) $, to use the identities
$$1+x=2\cos^2(t) \text{ and } 1-x=2\sin^2(t)$$

The new equation will be
$$f\Big(1-\frac{2}{\cos^2(t)}\Big)+f\Big(\frac{2}{\sin^2(t)}-1\Big)=$$
$$\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)$$

I think that this approach won't allow me the get the answer.
Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Let $g(x) = (x-3)/(x+1)$. Find $g^{-1} (x)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin $ g^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+3}{1-x} $

Comment: Your functional equation should hold only for $x \neq \pm1$.

Comment: Further hints in white font (highlight to view): 1) $\color{white} {\text{Find }g^2(x)} $ OR 2) $\color{white} {\text{Find } f(2)} $

Comment: @CalvinLin  the thing that makes it go is your $g(g(g(x))) = x$

Comment: Note in retrospect: This is problem 236 in Putnam & Beyond

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute in $x\mapsto\frac{x-3}{x+1}$. Then we have
$$f\left(\frac{x+3}{1-x}\right)+f\left(x\right)=\frac{x-3}{x+1}$$
Now substitute again $x\mapsto \frac{x-3}{x+1}$,

$$f(x)+f\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right)=\frac{x+3}{1-x}$$

Now add these two to get

$$2f(x)+f\left(\frac{x+3}{1-x}\right)+f\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}\right)=\frac{x-3}{x+1}+\frac{x+3}{1-x}$$
$$2f(x)=\frac{x-3}{x+1}+\frac{x+3}{1-x}-x$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-3}{x+1}+\frac{x+3}{1-x}-x\right)$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I am having trouble following here. In particular, how did you get the last 2 lines?

Comment: @Mike I used the original F.E.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I see it now--I think! I do need to look at this more closely in a bit. But, an extra line or two of explanation would probably be helpful to the reader.

Comment: @TheBestMagician As you stay longer, you'll get used to random downvotes. Just ignore them if the downvoter doesn't leave a comment pointing out an issue in your post.

Comment: Brilliant! This hinges not only on the fact that the second argument of $f$ is the inverse of the first argument, but that composing the first argument with itself equals the second argument.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes, its a common technique in these problems. But I just found it by messing around, nothing sophisticated.

Comment: I suspect it will apply whenever the graphs of the arguments are not only symmetric wrt $y=x$ but also wrt $y=-x$.

Comment: I didn't say that exactly right, but look at the graphs.

Comment: Well it will certainly apply when they are inverses

Comment: the Mobius transformation $m(x) = \frac{x-3}{x+1}$   cubes to the identity transformation, which is why the initial lines work out nicely. $f(m(x))  + f(m^2(x) ) = m^3 (x) $  where $m^2(x) $ means $m(m(x))$  and  $m^3(x) $ means $m(m(m(x))),$  while  $m(m(m(x))) =x.$

Comment: As @WillJagy mentioned above, the important thing is $g^3(x) = x$. Once we demonstrate the function is periodic (for a given $x$), we're just solving the system of linear equations (which has a unique solution for an odd period, infinitely many solutions for an even period). $\quad$ If the function is non-periodic (for a given starting value), then we have an infinite number of solutions by setting $f(x) = a, f(g(x)) = b$ and iterating accordingly (EG $f( g^{-1} (x) ) = x - b$).  $\quad$ In particular, for "nice" olympiad questions, you're almost guaranteed to have a periodic $g(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting!

Answer (score 3):

Let $h(x)=f(\frac{x-3}{x+1})$. Then the functional equation becomes
$$\tag1 h(x)+h(-x)=x\qquad\text{for }x\ne\pm1.$$
There are obviously many such $h$. In fact, if $k\colon(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}\to\Bbb R$ is **arbitrary,** we can set
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}k(x)&x>0\\x-k(x)&x<0\\0&x=0\end{cases} $$
and obtain a solution for $(1)$.
As the inverse of $x\mapsto \frac{x-3}{x+1}$ is (also) $x\mapsto \frac{x+3}{1-x}$, we obtain a solution
$$ f(x)=h(\tfrac{x+3}{1-x})$$
of the original functional equation.

Comment: Your $h(-x)$ might not be the thing you want it to be. BTW you can read the answers/comments posted by others.

Answer (score 0):

Set $u= \frac{x-3}{x+1}$ the equation becomes $f(u)+f(\frac{u+3}{1-u})=\frac{u+3}{1-u}$

Set $v=\frac{x+3}{1-x}$ the equation becomes $f(\frac{v-3}{v+1})+f(v)=\frac{v-3}{v+1}$

Now replace all dummy variables with $y$ and solve for $f(x)$,

1. $$A+B=y$$

2.$$B+C=\frac{y+3}{1-y}$$

3. $$A+C=\frac{y-3}{y+1}$$
   Can you finish it?

Comment: Could you check your equations. It seems to me that the very first sentence is wrong.

Comment: @WhatsUp Should be right now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).